# Quicksort random numbers in listbox + IMG

Tags: c#

I am trying to Quicksort 10 random numbers within an listbox. But i cant use the method on my random iar, can anyone give me some advice.

Code behind button:

```
         private void btnSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int n = 10;
        int[] iar = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < iar.Length; i++)
        {
            iar[i] = r.Next(0, 20);
            lb1.Items.Add(iar[i]);

        //here is the error i want to fill lb2 with the quicksorted array 
        // using the quicksort method

            Quicksort(iar, 0, iar.Length - 1);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < iar.Length; i++)
        {
            lb2.Items.Add(iar[i]);
        }
    }
```

Quicksort method

```
 public static void Quicksort(IComparable[] elements, int left, int right)
    {
        int i = left, j = right;
        IComparable pivot = elements[(left + right) / 2];

        while (i <= j)
        {
            while (elements[i].CompareTo(pivot) < 0)
            {
                i++;
            }
            while (elements[j].CompareTo(pivot) > 0)
            {
                j--;
            } 
            if (i <= j)
            {
                // Swap
                IComparable tmp = elements[i];
                elements[i] = elements[j];
                elements[j] = tmp;

                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        // Recursive calls
        if (left < j)
        {
            Quicksort(elements, left, j);
        }
        if (i < right)
        {
            Quicksort(elements, i, right);
        }
    }

}
```

ERRORS:

Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int[]' to 'System.IComparable[]'
Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'Quicksort.FrmQuicksort.Quicksort(System.IComparable[], int, int)' has some invalid arguments

Thanxs for looking:)

Comment: "I think the method is good but i can't debug it." - you'll have to elaborate on that, because the most likely answer this will get is "use a debugger". More so if the point of doing the sort by hand is because you're learning algorithms.

Comment: Well, IComparable[] is very different from int[] and that's the source of both errors.

Comment: When creating an unsorted array of string elements. It does work.

Comment: String is a class that implements IComparable. int is a primitive that does not.

Comment: Oh ok can you give any advice how to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the given context there is no real need to specify `IComparable` rather than `int` because you are only ever using integers. You're also calling `QuickSort` as each number is generated when it will work best if you run the `QuickSort` algorithm on the already generated list so move the statement outside the loop. Also bare in mind that there are better sorting algorithms for sorting tiny amounts of data like this.

#### Click Event Handler:

```
private void btnSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int n = 10;
    int[] iar = new int[n];

    //Generate random numbers and store them in the Unsorted ListBox
    for (int i = 0; i < iar.Length; i++)
    {
        iar[i] = r.Next(0, 20);
        lb1.Items.Add(iar[i]);
    }

    //Sort the random numbers array
    Quicksort(iar, 0, iar.Length - 1);

    //Now the array is sorted put it in the Sorted Listbox
    for (int i = 0; i < iar.Length; i++)
    {
        lb2.Items.Add(iar[i]);
    }
}
```

#### QuickSort Function

```
//Take an array of integers not an array of IComparable
public static void Quicksort(int[] elements, int left, int right)
{
    int i = left;
    int j = right;

    int pivot = elements[(left + right) / 2];

    while (i <= j)
    {
        while (elements[i].CompareTo(pivot) < 0)
        {
            i++;
        }
        while (elements[j].CompareTo(pivot) > 0)
        {
            j--;
        }


        if (i <= j)
        {
            // Swap
            int tmp = elements[i];
            elements[i] = elements[j];
            elements[j] = tmp;

            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    // Recursive calls
    if (left < j)
    {
        Quicksort(elements, left, j);
    }
    if (i < right)
    {
        Quicksort(elements, i, right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah first i tested it with an string of element, like pete said int doensn't implements IComparable.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've declared your `Quicksort` method to take an array of `IComparable` objects, you need to pass it an array of `IComparable` objects, not an array of `int`s. One obvious solution would be to declare a wrapper class:

```
    class MyQuicksortableInt : IComparable
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        // Implementation of IComparable left as an exercise for the reader;
        // see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IComparable.aspx for details
    }
```

Change `iar` to be of type `MyQuicksortableInt[]`, and your existing `Quicksort` code will accept it happily.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
public static void Quicksort<T>(T[] elements, int left, int right) where T:IComparable<T>
```

instead of

```
public static void Quicksort(IComparable[] elements, int left, int right)
```

and use T everywhere after that instead of IComparable